# AWS trusted entity with multiple principal types and condition

Tags: amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws, aws-policies, aws-roles

I have a Terraform code that generates a trusted entity like this that is attached to a role for cross-account access:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::444555666:root",
                "Service": "backup.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "sts:ExternalId": "444-555-666-777-888"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If I intend to allow the AWS account with an externalId to assume the role and I also want the AWS backup service to adopt the role, is the generated resource policy correct?
I don't know if the policies engine will pick the condition and try to apply it to the account and  also to the service, which is not desired.

Anybody knows if this is correct? are these kind of more complex rules documented by AWS?, I only have found info about simpler rules

I guess a way to ensure the correctness would be to separate both needs into different statements, but this is what the Terraform generates out of the provided HCL.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The statement will not be in effect until the condition is meet according to the [AWS condition documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition.html).

You will need to have another trust statement such as the example below.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "backup.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "backup.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "sts:ExternalId": "444-555-666-777-888"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Composite principal - Represents a principal that has multiple types of principals(AWS, Service)

A composite principal cannot have conditions.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.CompositePrincipal.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).